# How to override arguments in layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout

module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="order.comments" template="Magento_Sales::order/order_comments.phtml" before="sales.order.info.links"/>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="sales.order.view" cacheable="false" after="sales.order.info.links">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/items.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.items.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="sales_order_item_pager"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
                        <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="info" name="sales.order.info" after="sales.order.view"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

I want to change only colspan="4" to colspan="7"

```
       <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="7" class="mark"</argument>
```

I tried,

app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="7" class="mark"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
   </body>
```

Page is getting overrided but some phtml files are missing. It is not overrided in proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add second argument, i mean

> ```
> <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
> ```

so it should look like

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="7" class="mark"</argument>
            <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
   </body>
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: still some blocks are getting missed

Comment: what blocks? about taxes?

Comment: side menu bar is not getting displayed. I have attached screenshot for your reference

Comment: try set colspan="4" (like original) but in your custom file, we will see if its problem with page layout or your file

Comment: still same issue

Comment: another case, why you put   layout="1column" in first line, original file look like this in my project:
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

Comment: and add "                    <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/>
" like in original file below arguments

Comment: i removed 1 column and also added block. Still no effect.

Comment: and when you remove your file everything is ok?

Comment: yes, it calls default file

Comment: and when you change colspan to "7" in default file it works like you want to?

Comment: yes, i get expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="7" class="mark"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```